# Generating radio buttons across templates with Thymeleaf-Spring

Tags: spring, radio-button, thymeleaf

I'm having trouble creating a dynamic form with the behavior I would like. I think I have a solution, but I think there has to be a better one out there.

I'm using Thymeleaf-Spring for the view.

**The Goal**
I'm creating a dynamic form which will include a table containing postal addresses. Of the available addresses, one is to be marked as primary. See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RockfordSP/jLyk2/6/embedded/result/) for an example.

**The Problem**

Short version - Each row has a radio button that I need to have act as a check box at the row level (already accepted this will have to be done through JS) and act like a radio button at the table level.

The table body is set up using the following code.

```
<tr th:each="addr : ${addresses}" th:include="address :: row"
    th:with="prefix=__${prefix}__.address[__${addrStat.index}__]."/>
```

The prefix variable assignment is there because this table is nested a couple levels down on the form. All it's doing is appending extra data to the already existing prefix.

The address fragment being pulled in looks like this (condensed formatting here for brevity):

```
<tr th:fragment="row">
    <td>
        <input type="text" th:field="*{__${prefix}__line1}"/>
        <input type="text" th:field="*{__${prefix}__line2}"/>
    </td>
    <td><input type="text" th:field="*{__${prefix}__city}"/></td>
    <td><select th:field="*{__${prefix}__state}"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" th:field="*{__${prefix}__zip}"/></td>
    <td><select th:field="*{__${prefix}__type}"/></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" th:field="*{__${prefix}__valid}"/></td>
    <td>
        <input type="radio"
               th:field="*{__${prefix}__primary}"
               th:value="*{__${prefix}__primary}"
               th:checked="*{__${prefix}__primary}"/>
    </td>
</tr>
```

A little bit of jQuery will be put in place to ensure the element's value is `true` when the radio button is checked and `false` otherwise.

The issue is when Thymeleaf generates each of these rows, each radio button is assigned a unique name and id based on the value in `th:field`. This of course produces the unwanted behavior of each radio button being within its own group. They can all be selected at the same time, rather than only one in the table being selected at any given time.

My first attempted resolution was to modify the parent row to include a new `group` variable:

```
<tr th:each="addr: ${addresses}" th:include="address :: row"
    th:with="group='__${prefix}__primaryAddress',  
             prefix='__${prefix}__address[__${addrStat.index}__].'"/>
```

And then replace the `th:field` attribute on the radio button with individual `th:id` and `th:name` attributes:

```
<input type="radio"
       th:id="'__${prefix}__primary'"
       th:name="${group}"
       th:value="*{__${prefix}__primary}"
       th:checked="*{__${prefix}__primary}"/>
```

This gave the desired behavior on the form, but at the cost of losing the value on post back. Thymeleaf-Spring could no longer wire the form element to the object property. This is of course unacceptable.

**Current Solution**
My current solution, which I don't particularly like, is to stick with the `th:field` attribute wired to the object property and include a `data-group` attribute which will allow me to enforce the grouping through jQuery.

```
<input type="radio"
    th:field="*{__${prefix}__primary}"
    th:value="*{__${prefix}__primary}"
    th:checked="*{__${prefix}__primary}"
    th:attr="data-group=${group}"/>
```

Like I said, I don't particularly like this solution because I feel like I'm overriding (or maybe duplicating) the standard behavior of radio buttons, but I can't find any other way around it. Thymeleaf just doesn't seem to be able to handle radio button lists across objects at this point.

I assume others have come across this same limitation. How did you overcome it? Is my current solution the best currently available? Can anyone offer a better alternative?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is to select only one radio button within the form. Because You still required to apply unique names to radio buttons to maintain the Object Oriented approach. You can apply following JavaScript to enforce selecting only one item and deselect remaining on the same page:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $("input[type=radio]").change(function() {
        $('input[type=radio]:checked').not(this).prop('checked', false);
    });
});
```

You can change the selector if you have another set of radio buttons on this page.